# How to join Multiple excel columns with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm pulling data from excel and want to join multiple columns in to one and separate them by a comma. This columns share the same "Part Number" and If you look at the table under the "description code" FAB, It has multiple columns for the same code and I want to join them into one. My current code only pulls one of the columns.
Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated

TABLE
[image: Table]

```
Bag["Features"] =  Lookup.GetLookup("Eibach-C1")
  .Where(x=> x["E05"] == "FAB")
  .ToDictionary(x => new Tuple<string, string>(x["B15"], x["C05"]));
```

```
var C1CodeKey = new Tuple <string, string>(In["B15"], "FAB");

if(Bag["C1Codes"].ContainsKey(C1CodeKey))
{
  value = Bag["C1Codes"][C1CodeKey]["C10"];
}
else
{
  value = "";
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to open the excel files?

Answer (score 0):

High level, I think you should create a class to store the Excel data.

Then read in the Excel data and deserialize to a `List<PartData>`

Then use Linq to shape the `List`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inData = new List<PartData>{
            new PartData{
                PartNumber = "0175.225.0150",
                DescriptionCode = "DES",
                Description = "EIBACK LINEAR TENDER SPRING"
            },
            new PartData{
                PartNumber = "0175.225.0150",
                DescriptionCode = "FAB",
                Description = "Available in linear or progressive rates"
            },
            new PartData{
                PartNumber = "0175.225.0150",
                DescriptionCode = "FAB",
                Description = "Each spring individually tested"
            }
        };
        var shapedData = inData.GroupBy(i => new{i.PartNumber, i.DescriptionCode})
            .Select(i=> new{
                PartNumber = i.Key.PartNumber,
                DescriptionCode = i.Key.DescriptionCode,
                Description = string.Join(", ", i.Select(j => j.Description))
            });

        foreach(var dataItem in shapedData){
        Console.WriteLine(dataItem);
        }
        
    }
}
public class PartData{
    public string PartNumber {get;set;}
    public string DescriptionCode {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Output:

> { PartNumber = 0175.225.0150, DescriptionCode = DES, Description = EIBACK LINEAR TENDER SPRING }

> { PartNumber = 0175.225.0150, DescriptionCode = FAB, Description = Available in linear or progressive rates, Each spring individually tested }

see:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/CGN7qy